# OpenGL Flickering when vector is multiplied

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working on an OpenGL assignment that requires us to incorporate Phong lighting model. However, I am seeing flickers when I tries to multiply two 1x3 vectors together.

Double swapping is enabled, and so is mipmap.

Examples:

> color = texture(myTextureSampler, UV).rgb * vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);

[image]

> color = texture(myTextureSampler, UV).rgb * vec3(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);

[image]

> color = texture(myTextureSampler, UV).rgb * 0.9;

[image]

> color = texture(myTextureSampler, UV).rgb * vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

[image]
(Yes... that's a gif)

**UPDATE**: even this flickers:

> color = vec3(0.9, 0.1, 0.2);

[image]

Full source code is [here](https://gist.github.com/isaackwan/763e83a59d677dfd9fb98e5a3e8d85a5) which is based on the [opengl-tutorials.org code](https://github.com/opengl-tutorials/ogl/tree/master/tutorial08_basic_shading) but (hopefully) this question will be updated very soon with a minimal reproduction of the problem.

Cheers

Comment: Multiplying a vector by a vector does a member by member multiplication, therefore, it might not do what you think it does.

try multiplying the diffuse colour by a single value instead, and setting the output to a vec4:
`out vec4 color;`

`color = vec4(MaterialDiffuseColor*0.5,1.0);`

Comment: This seems far more likely to be a bug elsewhere than to be due to multiplication. So you'll have to provide your actual source code.

Comment: @IanYoung thanks for the pointer! Turns out that it was caused by the fact that I turned `GL_BLEND` on but yielded an output of `vec3`. I am going to call this a day and post this as a "solution" tomorrow. Thanks again, now I can finally sleep safe and sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the issue is that OpenGL is expecting RGBA (`vec4`) output instead of RGB (`vec3`) because I enabled `GL_BLEND`.

**Solution 1**: Turn off `GL_BLEND` by removing `glEnable(GL_BLEND)`.

**Solution 2**: return a `vec4`. You can use `vec4(existing_vec3, 1.0)` to "pad" it into a 1x4 vector.